# Factor order within faceted dotplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the plotting order within facets of a faceted dotplot in ggplot2, but I can't get it to work. Here's my melted dataset:

```
> London.melt
                      country medal.type count
1                 South Korea       gold    13
2                       Italy       gold     8 
3                      France       gold    11
4                   Australia       gold     7
5                       Japan       gold     7
6                     Germany       gold    11
7  Great Britain & N. Ireland       gold    29
8          Russian Federation       gold    24
9                       China       gold    38
10              United States       gold    46
11                South Korea     silver     8
12                      Italy     silver     9
13                     France     silver    11
14                  Australia     silver    16
15                      Japan     silver    14
16                    Germany     silver    19
17 Great Britain & N. Ireland     silver    17
18         Russian Federation     silver    26
19                      China     silver    27
20              United States     silver    29
21                South Korea     bronze     7
22                      Italy     bronze    11
23                     France     bronze    12
24                  Australia     bronze    12
25                      Japan     bronze    17
26                    Germany     bronze    14
27 Great Britain & N. Ireland     bronze    19
28         Russian Federation     bronze    32
29                      China     bronze    23
30              United States     bronze    29
```

and here's my plot command:

```
qplot(x = count, y = country, data = London.melt, geom = "point", facets = medal.type ~.)
```

The result I get is as follows:

[image: R plot]

The facets themselves appear in the order I want in this plot. Within each facet, however, I'd like to sort by count. That is, for each type of medal, I'd like the country that won the greatest number of those medals on top, and so on. The procedure I have used successfully when there are no facets (say we're only looking at gold medals) is to use the  `reorder` function on the factor `country`, sorting by `count` but this doesn't work in the present example.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Please display your dataset using `dput(London.melt)`, so it can be easily imported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here a solution using paste, free scales and some relabeling

```
library(ggplot2)
London.melt$medal.type<-factor(London.melt$medal.type, levels = c("gold","silver","bronze"))
# Make every country unique
London.melt$country_l <- with(London.melt, paste(country, medal.type, sep = "_"))
#Reorder the unique countrys
q <- qplot(x = count, y = reorder(country_l, count), data = London.melt, geom = "point") +   facet_grid(medal.type ~., scales = "free_y")
# Rename the countries using the original names
q + scale_y_discrete("Country", breaks = London.melt$country_l, label = London.melt$country)
```

[image]

Comment: @ttmaccer You can reduce the amount of typing by using `within`: `London.melt <- within(London.melt, medal.type <- factor(medal.type, ... ))`

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously quite late, and some of what I'm doing may have not been around 6 years ago, but I came across this question while doing a similar task. I'm always reluctant to set tick labels with a vector—it feels safer to use a function that can operate on the original labels.

To do that, I'm creating a factor ID column based on the country and the medal, with some delimiter character that doesn't already appear in either of those columns—in this case, `_` works. Then with `forcats::fct_reorder`, I can order that column by `count`. The last few levels of this column are below, and should correspond to the country + medal combinations with the highest counts.

```r
library(tidyverse)

London_ordered <- London.melt %>%
  mutate(id = paste(country, medal.type, sep = "_") %>%
           as_factor() %>%
           fct_reorder(count, .fun = min))

levels(London_ordered$id) %>% tail()
#> [1] "Great Britain & N. Ireland_gold" "United States_silver"           
#> [3] "United States_bronze"            "Russian Federation_bronze"      
#> [5] "China_gold"                      "United States_gold"
```

Then use this ID as your y-axis. On its own, you'd then have very long labels that include the medal type. Because of the unique delimiter, you can write an inline function for the y-axis labels that will remove the delimiter and any word characters that come after it, leaving you with just the countries. Moving the facet specification to a `facet_wrap` function lets you then set the free y-scale.

```r
qplot(x = count, y = id, data = London_ordered, geom = "point") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) str_remove(x, "_\\w+$")) +
  facet_wrap(~ medal.type, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do with qplot. Not exactly what you asked for but closer. OOOPs I see you already figured that out.

```
q <- qplot(x = count, y = reorder(country, count), data = London.melt, geom = "point", facets = medal.type ~.)
```

Here's a `dput` version so others can improve:

```
dput(London.melt)
structure(list(country = structure(c(9L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 
6L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("Australia", 
"China", "France", "Germany", "Great Britain & N. Ireland", "Italy", 
"Japan", "Russian Federation", "South Korea", "United States"
), class = "factor"), medal.type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("bronze", 
"gold", "silver"), class = "factor"), count = c(13L, 8L, 11L, 
7L, 7L, 11L, 29L, 24L, 38L, 46L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 14L, 19L, 
17L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 17L, 14L, 19L, 32L, 23L, 
29L)), .Names = c("country", "medal.type", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"))
```

Comment: Exactly as far as I came. I'm stuck too. I also played with the `order` aesthetic, but that does not seem to do much, unfortunately.