# Ordering of faceted stacked barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I have a dataset like the below and am trying to get an ordered faceted stacked barplot. I have looked at some answers on SO particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012265/ordering-labeling-and-facet-control-in-r-using-ggplot2) one to come up with my plot but am not sure why this does not work on one particular bar of my stacked barplot

```
structure(list(reg = c("J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J", 
"KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "RI", 
"RI", "RI", "RI", "SU", "SU", "SU", "SU", "SU", "SU", "SA", "SA", 
"SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", "SA", 
"SA", "SA", "SA"), org = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("WR", "MS", "SM", "AA", "AAL", 
"PH", "P3", "SD", "HS"), class = "factor"), level = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
"R"), class = "factor"), share = c(6.94, 1.51, 3.01, 0.42, 1.58, 
0.24, 2.85, 0.19, 4.7, 0.5, 2.16, 5.32, 1.08, 1.26, 0.82, 1.11, 
1.8, 1.73, 2, 3.52, 5, 2, 1.29, 0.38, 0.72, 0.46, 0.44, 2.27, 
15.79, 13.74, 5.12, 16.21, 6.54, 11.16, 8.19, 10.91, 4.71, 5.32, 
0.45, 0.14, 1.03, 0.33, 5.04, 3.03), reg_l = c("J_R", "J_E", 
"J_R", "J_E", "J_R", "J_E", "J_R", "J_E", "KA_R", "KA_E", "KA_R", 
"KA_E", "KA_R", "KA_E", "KA_R", "KA_E", "KA_R", "KA_E", "RI_R", 
"RI_E", "RI_R", "RI_E", "SU_R", "SU_E", "SU_R", "SU_E", "SU_R", 
"SU_E", "SA_R", "SA_E", "SA_R", "SA_E", "SA_R", "SA_E", "SA_R", 
"SA_E", "SA_R", "SA_E", "SA_E", "SA_E", "SA_R", "SA_E", "SA_R", 
"SA_E")), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and here is my code right now

```
data$level <- as.factor(as.character(data$level))
data$reg_l <- with(data, paste(reg,level,sep = "_"))

data$org <- factor(data$org,levels=c("WR","MS","SM","AA","AAL","PH","P3","SD","HS"))

# plot
reg_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(reg_l,share),y = share,group=org)) +
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(level~.,ncol = 1,scales="free") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=org),colour=NA,width=0.75) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = data$reg_l, labels = data$reg) +
  xlab("\n") + 
  ylab("\n") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) +
  ggtitle("\n")

reg_plot
```

The image below is the plot I am getting now but some reason the `RI` bar does not seem to follow the order of `high` to `low` values

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `reorder` doesn't seem to respect the `facet_wrap` when using the aggregation function `sum`. Using `forcats::fct_reorder()` worked for me:

```
reg_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = forcats::fct_reorder(reg_l, share, .fun = sum),y = share,group=org)) +
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(level~.,ncol = 1,scales="free") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=org),colour=NA,width=0.75) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = data$reg_l, labels = data$reg) +
  xlab("\n") + 
  ylab("\n") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) +
  ggtitle("\n")

reg_plot
```

[image]